# Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1: Pipe a mp4 video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, mp4

I was piping a mp4 file and always got Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1.

I was trying to put -pix_fmt option in front of '-i inputfile', as in the ffmpeg output I found a message: unspecified pixel format but it seems not work

The ffmpeg outpus is here:  http://pastebin.com/8hNdLeQ2

By the way, the ffmpeg version I was using is the latest one from git repo

And the mp4 video clip is from a sumsung tablet.

The command I use: 
$ cat b2.mp4 | ./ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -c:a copy a.mp4

I also tried:

The video is at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oz0e51ggkbpgj0f/b2.mp4

Anyone can tell me how to pipe this mp4 video, Thanks,

Lewis